# NSMutableArray empty when accessed

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a NSMutableArray which I populate with the below code, however when I then access the array in the below code the array is empty?

This code fills the array

```
NSMutableArray *videos;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"kingdb5.sqlite"];
    db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
    if (![db open]) {
        return;
    }
    FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM mediaVideos"];
    if ([db hadError]) {
        NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
    }
    while ([s next]) {
        NSString *url = [s stringForColumnIndex:1];
        NSLog(url);
        [videos addObject:url];
    }


    ...
}
```

The NSLog(url) prints out the correct number of urls (which are also correct etc)

Then the array is accessed when a user presses a button with:

```
- (IBAction)playbutton_onclick:(id)sender {
    for (NSString *s in videos){
        NSLog(s);
    }
    NSString *file = [videos objectAtIndex:2];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Videos/%@", file]];
    NSLog(@"Now playing: %@", dataPath);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataPath];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController* viewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:viewController];
}
```

At this point the array is empty, the for loop prints nothing and getting the object at the index point returns null

Comment: If you don't create the video array it will be always at nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning on viewDidLoad you have to allocate the array:

```
videos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

For best practice you should make it a property and refer to it as self.videos.
See answer added by trojanfoe.

Comment: No. It should not be a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make `videos` an instance variable or property of the class:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *videos;

@end
```

And then allocate and initiailize it in the implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.videos = [NSMutableArray new];
    ...

}
```

And change all references of `videos` to `self.videos`.